# Can modern browser supports HTTP via UDP

Tags: http, udp

that's the question.
Dose anyone know?

I wonder If I could develop a UDP protocol  based application to enhance service response.

Comment: You could develop that protocol. You would have to add a layer on top of UDP (because HTTP requires guarantees that UDP does not provide). That layer would probably look uncannily like TCP...

Comment: Oh forgot to mention QUIC: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/QUIC -- so you aren't alone with the idea.

Answer (score 1):

There is a reason HTTP uses TCP. TCP provides reliability, e.g. no lost, no duplicate and no reordered data. This features are necessary, so that you don't get any broken content back from the server and no broken uploads. Of course you can re-implement this in UDP - but I doubt that you will have improved response time compared to TCP when you are done.